# Distorted navigation bar custom back button

Tags: iphone, ios

[image]

I have a custom back button and the button is not displaying as intended, it is being stretched, and even though the back button text is empty it is still  displaying the "back"
text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use this technique to make it work:

1. To get rid default title:

   ```
   [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-400.f, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   ```
2. Use resizable image:

   ```
   UIImage *backButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];         
   [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[backButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, backButton.size.width, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   ```

Comment: and that did work, thanks a ton :) and @Jano really appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
UIButton *back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
UIImage *image = ... your image
[back setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[back addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem *backbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];  
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backbi;
```

or post your code.

Comment: Actually i am using something like this

    UIImage *backButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]           setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton  forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: sorry if i am being a noob but the self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backbi; says 
property 'navigationItem' not found on object of type AppDelegate

Comment: self.navigationItem would only work when used from a view controller.